# Put border around certain sentences

Tags: tikz-pgf, line

I am writing a book on "Writing an Introduction" and I want to be able to show the organization of information, as in the following.[image]

Anyone knows what is the best way to put border around certain sentences?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What have you got so far? Please provide some code. Your tags suggest you are using Ti*k*Z for it. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: You can use this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282386/make-soul-highlight-span-lines or other options in soul package.

Comment: I used a picture editor to achieve what appears in the picture. It will be great if I can do it in latex. The book will be published in black and white so I cannot use the suggestion proposed by @percusse

Comment: @FaisalMustafa - obtaining a frame automatically would seem very difficult. Maybe some advanced LuaTeX hackery could achieve it, but I'm not certain. Alternatives: 1. even with b/w, you can use background color - a light gray should be o.k., if used judiciously and not all over the place; 2. font color (black vs gray) - might be easier on the eyes; 3. different font shapes.

Comment: Your publisher can convert it to B&W and make it gray.

Comment: Maybe I din't understand the question correct.  But why not building a simple paragraph (by inserting two blank lines)?  You could still use the macro `\marginpar` to insert "Move1" or "Move2" into the margin.  Could that be a solution?  Of course this suggestion will not draw any kind of boxes.  But maybe, it makes drawing them easier?

Comment: I had done [something similar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238459/tikzmark-declare-a-shape-imitating-span-in-html).

Comment: Any updates here? Does the provided link helped you?